# Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

**И пусть каждый твой прожитый день будет полон смысла**
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

Comment: А в каких местах Вы бы поставили в этом предложении запятые?

Comment: Если вы хотите задать новый вопрос, используйте https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Answer (score 3):

**И пусть каждый твой прожитый день будет полон смысла.**

В этом предложении запятые не требуются, потому что все три определения, относящиеся к одному существительному "день", являются неоднородными:

каждый — местоименное прилагательное;
твой — притяжательное местоимение;
прожитый — причастие (одиночное, стоит перед определяемым словом).

Они характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, в разных отношениях, то есть выражают признаки, относящиеся к разным родовым (общим) понятиям.

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html)

*А не встанешь, я все равно буду благодарен судьбе за **каждый твой прожитый день*** (О. Покровская); *...почему так важен **каждый твой прожитый день**, проведённый в духовной работе над собой...* (А. Новых).

P. S. В конце предложения необходима точка.

Answer (score 0):

***Что же делать? Вдруг будет так, что мы ничего не поймём, и не узнаем, и совершим ошибку всякую.***

Предложение немного стилизовано под старинные тексты, нейтральный стиль: ...*и совершим ошибки разного рода*.

**В целом текст  построен корректно, звучит  эмоционально, выразительно.**

Второе предложение **сложноподчиненное (СПП) с изъяснительным придаточным.**

Придаточное осложнено **однородными сказуемыми,** связанными повторяющимся союзом И...И, причем первый союз отсутствует.

В этом случае запятые ставятся, произношение с перечислительной интонацией.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, **кроме первого**, то **запятая ставится** между всеми однородными членами: Листья в поле пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

**Примечание**

Неясно, **почему в первом ответе разбирается другое предложение.**

Comment: Потому что автор вопроса его поменял! Посмотрите правку. Думаю, что надо вернуть назад. Автору предложить задать новый вопрос.